# Decoding JSON String From Facebook Graph API in PHP

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So here I was trying to decode the post and comments in php but since I don't know much on JSON, I stuck here and don't know what else to code to decode the URL from the Graph API I've made.

```
   $group_id ="1xxxxxxxxxxx3"; 
   $access_token ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
   $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/" . $group_id . "/feed 
   fields=comments{comments{message,from},message,from},message,from
   &access_token=".$access_token;

   $json= file_get_contents($url);
   $obj = json_decode($json, true);

 ?>
```

I really need your help and maybe give me some explanation to the problem I'm suffering right now.

The result should be showing like this. 
 [This is the result from the facebook page itself, I need these to come out in my own localhost pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlub1.png)

Comment: Assuming it was valid json to begin with then you have already decoded it using `json_decode`. If however you mean how do you process the decoded json you ought to add a sample of the data and identify the desired goals with processing.

Comment: What I want is how do I show the result as String to show if it decoded correctly @RamRaider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly then all you want to do next is determine if it decoded OK and display it? You can try using the `json_last_error()` like this

```
   $group_id ="1xxxxxxxxxxx3"; 
   $access_token ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
   $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/" . $group_id . "/feed 
   fields=comments{comments{message,from},message,from},message,from
   &access_token=".$access_token;

   $json= file_get_contents($url);
   $obj = json_decode($json, true);

   if( json_last_error()==JSON_ERROR_NONE ){
    echo '<pre>',print_r( $obj, true ),'</pre>';
   } else {
    echo 'json error: '.json_last_error();
   }
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thanks! Anyway, do you know how can I grab only specific value like, I only want "comments" and "name" to show when I run the php class?

Comment: We would need to see the data to know how to access specific elements

Answer (score 1):

To display the whole JSON object:

```
print_r($obj);
```

Then you analyse its structure, and loop accordingly, using "foreach".

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not executed the URL. You need to first execute the URL in order to get the response from the Facebook graph API. Something like

```
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
        $head = curl_exec($ch); 
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
        curl_close($ch); 
        var_dump($head);
```

Comment: What would the result be showing if I code all these?

Comment: you should get the result what you are looking at. Basically the response for your parameters which are posted to the Facebook graph API. The code above will actually make a request to the Facebook graph api using the provided URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you can be more elaborate with your question. Have you decoded the Json ? If yes then you can simply  use the JavaScript built-in function JSON.parse() to convert the string into a JavaScript object, and use the object in your page.